# non-recursive make constrict targets

Tags: makefile

Based on [this paper](http://evbergen.home.xs4all.nl/nonrecursive-make.html), I'm trying to rework a subset of my build system to be non-recursive. It's actually working pretty well. By default, I have part of my makefile `include` all the relevant directories via a template:

```
DIRECTORIES = dirA dirB ... etc ...

define import_template
dir := $(1)
include $(1)/Rules.mk
include Rules.mk
endef

$(foreach DIR,$(DIRECTORIES), \
    $(eval $(call import_template,$(DIR))))
```

Those `includes` build up a variables like `TGT_BIN`, a la the paper, that all works.

```
$ make # does the right thing
```

However, I want to provide the user the ability to make a subset of those directories. I know I can define `DIRECTORIES` like:

```
DIRECTORIES ?= dirA ...
```

So that:

```
$ make DIRECTORIES="dirB dirF"
```

works. But is there a way to write my makefile such that:

```
$ make -j12 dirB dirF
```

will do the same thing?

Comment: You don't need `?=` to make command line assigment like `make DIRECTORIES=` work. Command line assignment takes precedence. You need `?=` to prevent environment variables from being over-written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have per-directory variables of targets to build (e.g. `TGT_dirB`, `TGT_dirF`, etc.) then doing what you want should be as simple as adding:

```
$(eval $(DIR): $(TGT_$(DIR)))
```

to the `foreach` loop like this:

```
$(eval $(call import_template,$(DIR)))$(eval $(DIR): $(TGT_$(DIR)))
```

to add all the per-directory targets as pre-requisites of the directory targets.

And adding

```
.PHONY: $(DIRECTORIES)
```

somewhere in the makefile to make sure make realizes those are phony targets and don't actually mean the directories themselves.

Comment: Would the `.PHONY : $(DIRECTORIES)` line be equivalent to `.PHONY : $1 $(TGT_$1)` in the template?

Comment: To `.PHONY: $1` in the template, yes. I almost did that but the single line was clearer to explain I thought.

Comment: I can't get `$1 : $(TGT_$1)` to work. I think the `$1` in `TGT_$1` isn't expanded right away?

Comment: What do you mean you can't get it to work? What happens? Are you getting an error from make? What does `$(info Test: $1: $(TGT_$1))` output if you stick it in the template? What do you see in the `make -qp` output for one of those targets?

Comment: I get `Test: dirA:` and `Test: dirB:`. However, if I `$(info Test: $1: $(TGT_dirA))`, I get `Test: dirA:` and `Test: dirB: some targets from dirA`. Which is weird too, I thought I'd get the `dirA` targets in both places?

Comment: Hm... what is assigning to `TGT_dirA`? I assumed it was the `dirA/Rules.mk` file (or possibly the toplevel `dirA` file) is it not? You could try moving that line to the `foreach` loop directly and seeing if that helps get the assignment timing right. i.e. `$(eval $(call import_template,$(DIR)))$(eval $(DIR): $(TGT_$(DIR)))`

Comment: I have `dirA/Rules.mk` set some variables which are read by `Rules.mk` which sets `TGT_$(d)`. Adding that extra `eval` worked! Why though?

Comment: The `TGT_$(d)` assignment in `Rules.mk` doesn't occur until the expanded template value is handled by `eval` but the expansion of `$(TGT_$1)` is done *within* the value that `eval` will eventually see (so it isn't available yet). Moving that target outside of the `eval` and into its own means that you've sequenced the assignments correctly... I think.

Comment: Thanks! I'll buy that.

Comment: An `$(eval TGT_$(d) = ....)` in `Rules.mk` would have let the original work also I believe. Just as a further piece of information.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you a non-recursive [**prorab**](https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md) build system.

It allows you to have *independent* `makefile`'s in each directory while having  a master makefile for everything. So, you'll be able to build only part of your project tree by `cd`'ing to the right subdir and invoking `make`.