# makefile evaluation of variables in template call

Tags: c++, makefile

Consider this simple makefile that does very little:

```
define template
copy      := $(1)
$(info $(1) $(copy))

.PHONY    : rule_$(1)
rule_$(1) : VAR := $(1)
rule_$(1) :
    @echo $@ $(VAR)

all       : rule_$(1)
endef

$(foreach mode,DEBUG OPT, \
    $(eval $(call template,$(mode))))

.PHONY : all 
.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
```

I thought that this would create two rules, `rule_DEBUG` and `rule_OPT`, whose recipes would echo their names and arg. Furthermore, I thought that the `info` line would just print `DEBUG DEBUG` and then `OPT OPT`. However, I am wrong on both accounts. The `info` lines log:

```
DEBUG 
OPT DEBUG
```

And when I run `make`, I get back nothing but empty lines. If I run `make -p`, I do see this for `rule_OPT`:

```
rule_OPT:
#  Phony target (prerequisite of .PHONY).
#  Implicit rule search has not been done.
#  Implicit/static pattern stem: `'
#  File does not exist.
#  File has been updated.
#  Successfully updated.
# automatic
# @ := rule_OPT
# makefile (from `makefile', line 10)
# VAR := OPT
# automatic
# % := 
# automatic
# * := 
# automatic
# + := 
# automatic
# | := 
# automatic
# < := 
# automatic
# ^ := 
# automatic
# ? := 
# variable set hash-table stats:
# Load=9/32=28%, Rehash=0, Collisions=1/12=8%
#  recipe to execute (from `makefile', line 10):
        @echo
```

Looks like `@` and `VAR` have the values I want and expect - but why doesn't it `echo` correctly? It looks like if I have the recipe:

```
rule_$(1) :
    @echo $$@ $$(VAR)
```

That echos what I want, but I am still not sure how to `info` the `copy`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$(info)` output issue is what I explained in the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30897765/258523) of mine. You have an evaluative order problem. The assignments in the define aren't happening until the define expansion is processed by `eval` so your assigned variable value isn't visible until later. You need extra `eval`'s or post-`eval` expansion to do that.

Either

```
$(eval copy      := $(1))
```

in the template or splitting up the contents into multiple defines.

The problem with `@echo $(VAR)` is the same thing. That is being expanded by the `eval` of the `define`'s expansion and `$(VAR)` is unset at that point so you need `$$(VAR)` in the template to have a literal `$(VAR)` in the expanded recipe so that it works correctly and recipe execution time.

Comment: Thank you - I think I'm finally starting to get it.